# Why emulator is slow after Android Studio 2.3 update?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After I have updated my android studio to **2.3 & above**, emulators become slow and also I am also using **x86 system images**. I have also tried to use **Software Gles 2.0**[image: Software Gles]

as described in other recent  answers but nothing is working.
After starting up the emulator it stops on main screen and becomes un-clickable anywhere.
Even **Api 15 & 16** emulators slowed down even though they are not heavy.
I have also re-downloaded android sdk.
**note: I do not want to use gennymotion or any other emulator**
please provide any help regarding Android Emulator.

Comment: I think you should ask this question to Android Studio support, as only they know, why it is slow.

Comment: @VladMatvienko asking here because if anyone already facing issue can help me..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the grahics to Hardware-GLES 2. Then run your emulator to compare your result. I think it is much more faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all these options but nothing worked, its only working after I have uninstall and reinstall the new android studio 2.3.

Please read my blog for the correct solution.
http://www.remiblog.com/programming/android-emulator-slow-update-android-studio-2-3/